# Nested Linear Layouts not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

Only the first nested linear layout is showing up, any idea why? The first textView inside the 2nd linear layout shows up, and the layout is the proper height, but none if it's contents can be viewed.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100">
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:background="#FAFA25"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textColor="#222222"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/width" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/totalWidth"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/numOne"
        android:layout_weight="62"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/numTwo"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="38"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#222222"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="Calculate" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

linearLayout3 , orientation is horizontal, in case you are wondering why, default orientation is horizontal. and since textView has layout_width="fill_parent", the next child will not show up.

change the orientation to vertical.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, it was the orientation to vertical that did it. Doest orientation default to horizontal?